# Use regroup with datetimefield

Tags: python, django

I want to regroup a queryset in my template :

```
{% regroup events by date as events_group %}
    {% for event in events_group %}
          <div class="time-label">
              <span class="bg-danger">
              {{ event.grouper }}
```

It's works but the "date" is a datetimefield. I want to group my results per day.
Today the results are displayed like :

```
10 Oct 2020 16:59 
event1

10 Oct 2020 16:55
event2

10 Oct 2020 16:54
event3

09 Oct 2020 12:59 
event4

09 Oct 2020 11:59 
event5
```

I want :

```
10 Oct 2020
event1
event2
event3

09 Oct 2020
event4
event5
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fund a solution :

```
{% regroup events by date|date:"d M, Y" as events_group %}
      {% for eventgroup in events_group %}
           <div class="time-label">
                <span class="bg-danger">
                {{ eventgroup.grouper }}
```